# How to pass multiple maps to a function in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

For example: I want to pass the container information to a function and formulate a yaml string for it like

```
def containers(List<Map> data) {

    def yamlString = """
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: container.name
              image: container.image
              workingDir: /home/jenkins
              resources:
                requests:
                  memory: "66Mi"
                  cpu: "44m"
                limits:
                  memory: "99Mi"
                  cpu: "88m"
              command:
                - cat
              tty: true
    }
    """
    return yamlString
}

containers ([name: 'maven', image: 'repo/maven:3.5.2-jdk-8'],
            [name: 'ansible', image: 'repo/ansible:3.5.2-jdk-8'])
```

I know that the syntax and the approach is completely wrong. I am new to groovy

Answer (score 0):

```
def containers(List<Map> data) {
    data.collect {
        """
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: $it.name
              image: $it.image
              workingDir: /home/jenkins
              resources:
                requests:
                  memory: "66Mi"
                  cpu: "44m"
                limits:
                  memory: "99Mi"
                  cpu: "88m"
              command:
                - cat
              tty: true
        """
    }
}
```

Will return a list of strings